# Proof of Bivariate Distribution from normality of linear combination

Tags: normal-distribution

We know that if X1 and X2 are normally distributed random variables, then a linear combination Z = a*X1 + b*X2 will be normally distributed. IS there a  proof for the converse, i.e. if Z = a*X1 + b*X2 is normally distributed, then X1 and X2 have a bivariate normal distribution (in this case, X1 and X2 are just two random variables)?

Comment: Neither statement is true.

Comment: yes there are conditions and I didn't feel the need to write them down. the question should still be understood

Answer (score 3):

Be careful here, linear combination of independent normal r.v.'s is again normal, but mere normality cannot guarantee such result, the easiest counter example is $X_2=-X_1$.

The converse is not true as well. In fact, it is possible to construct $X_1$, $X_2$ such that $X_1+X_2$ is normal and $\operatorname{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=0$, and still $(X_1,X_2)$ is not bi-variate normal, see 10.5 of Stoyanov's *Counterexamples in Probability*.

That said, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then the converse statement is true, due to the [Lévy-Cramér theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/L%C3%A9vy-Cram%C3%A9r_theorem).